# date-fns MMMM formatting is broken in Russian locale

Tags: time, momentjs, datetime-format, time-format, date-fns

Lets assume we have the following date: 2019, 11, 1.

I want to display only the month's name, but `MMMM` formatting results into "ноября", when I expect to get "ноябрь".

It works OK in **moment.js** (locale: ru):

```
// if format starts with month name
moment([2019, 11, 1]).format('MMMM') => 'ноябрь'

// if format doesn't start with month name
moment([2019, 11, 1]).format('DD MMMM') => '1 ноября'
```

I would like to switch to moment.js, although I am already utilizing the library which strictly depends on **date-fns**. How can I achieve the format to show the month's name correctly in Russian language?

[date-fns's GitHub repo](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change MMMM to LLLL

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this problem in use case for react-datepicker was to pass month name in cyrilic as format.

```
const getMonthName = (date) => {
    const months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
    return months[date.getMonth()];
};

<DatePicker dateFormatCalendar={ getMonthName(new Date()) } />

format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), getMonthName(new Date(2014, 1, 11)))
```

Worked under my limited use case